# Expression not getting evaluated in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
TEST1=`echo $QUERY_DAYS3 | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $TEST1

TEST2=`echo $QUERY_DAYS3 | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $TEST2

mailx -s "Data Report" -r uname@host.com uname@host.com <<EOF

Error Percentage: $((100 * ($TEST2/ $TEST1)))

EOF
```

In my bash Shell script I have the above code from which I am sending email. But when I check my email I always see `Error Percentage` written like as it is written in my above code. It is not evaluating the multiplication and division expression.

I am running the above script like this-

```
sh -x test1.sh
```

In the email I get like this-

```
Error  Percentage: $((100 * (183563 / 3793277)))
```

I am running `SunOS`.

May be I need to use `Back-Ticks` here?

**Update:-**

My updated script that I am using currently-

```
TEST1=`echo $QUERY_DAYS3 | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $TEST1

TEST2=`echo $QUERY_DAYS3 | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $TEST2

mailx -s "Data Report" -r uname@host.com uname@host.com <<EOF

Error Percentage: $(( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1)

EOF
```

I am running it like this below-

```
sh -c 'exec ./test.sh'
```

After trying the suggestion given by lot of peoples. I am getting this error-

```
./test.sh: command substitution: line 176: syntax error near unexpected token `/'
./test.sh: command substitution: line 176: `( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1'
```

What wrong I am doing now? Any thoughts?

**Update:-**

After making changes, it start working-

```
Mismatch  Percentage: $((( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1))
```

But in the email, the percentage I get was rounded to only one figure like `4` only instead of showing as `4.34563235` How can I get full numbers instead of getting rounded off to one digit.?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, but you might want to use `( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1` in there, otherwise you'll always get a percentage rounded to zero.

Comment: Are you certain `bash` is used as the shell? What does `echo $SHELL` give?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives me this `/bin/sh`...

Comment: @usta, agreed, doesn't appear that bash is being used. Ran his script under bash and sh under SunOS, works as expected under bash

Comment: IIRC, Solaris's `/bin/sh` is Bourne shell, not `bash`, at least up to Solaris 10...

Comment: @user1419563 you can (and should) open a new question for... new questions. This behaviour leads to useless information for other users (accreting unrelated noise) and is possibly perceived as ['help vampiring'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) (voting to close as too localized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect it to run under bash, if you explicitely tell `sh` to execute it...
Try

```
bash -x test1.sh
```

Having

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line, will only work if you *directly* execute the script:

```
./test1.sh
```

It needs to be 'executable' for that to work

```
chmod +x test1.sh
```

**Update**

```
Error Percentage: $(( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1)
```

needs to be

```
Error Percentage: $((( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1))
```

Comment: If I need to explicitly tell `sh` to execute it, then is there any way I can run this by using `sh`? May be using `back-ticks`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. And I am getting an error. I have updated my question. Any thoughts why is it happening?

Comment: @user1419563 yeah, too few parentheses. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I have one final question that I have updated in my question. My result is getting rounded off instead of showing full numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the script indeed runs with bash.
The standard way to do it is to have this as the first line in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Don't have any experience with SunOS though, so not sure if that will work there or will need some slight modification.

Edit: now that it runs with bash, looks like you need it to be:

```
Error Percentage: $(( ( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1 ))
```

Update: bash does integer arithmetic only. For floating-point arithmetic you can do

```
Error Percentage: `echo "scale=8; ( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1" | bc`
```

This will use [bc](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/bc1.html) instead of the shell for doing the computation.

Comment: I have this as the first line in my script.  `#!/bin/bash`. Will this not work?

Comment: @user1419563 It will, provided that /bin/bash exists. However, as sehe already mentioned, it won't work if you invoke the script with sh explicitly.

Comment: Updated my question with the error I am getting after making changes. Any suggestions will be of great help.